# Shouldn't ROUGE-1 precision be equal to BLEU with w=(1, 0, 0, 0) when brevity penalty is 1?

Tags: nlp, model-evaluations, ngrams

I am trying to evaluate a NLP model using BLEU and ROUGE. However, I am a bit confused about the difference between those scores. While I am aware that ROUGE is aimed at recall whilst BLEU measures precision, all ROUGE implementations I have come across also output precision and the F-score. The original ROUGE paper only briefly mentions precision and the F-score, therefore I am a bit unsure about what meaning they have to ROUGE. Is ROUGE mainly about recall and the precision and F-score are just added as a compliment, or is the ROUGE considered to be the combination of those three scores?

What confuses me even more is that to my understanding ROUGE-1 precision should be equal to BLEU when using the weights (1, 0, 0, 0), but that does not seem to be the case.
The only explanation I could have for this is the brevity penalty. However, I checked that the accumulated lengths of the references are shorter than the length of the hypothesis, which means that the brevity penalty is 1.
Nonetheless, BLEU with w = (1, 0, 0, 0) scores 0.55673 while ROUGE-1 precision scores 0.7249.

What am I getting wrong?

I am using [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/translate/bleu_score.html) to evaluate BLEU and [rouge-metric](https://github.com/li-plus/rouge-metric) for ROUGE.

Comment: Can you add a short example hypothesis/reference that give different results?

Comment: @BenReiniger while trying to find an example for you I realised that the scores are not different when used on individual sentences (unless of course the hypothesis is shorter than the reference, which makes sense due to the brevity penalty). However, when calculating ROUGE-1 and BLEU with w = (1, 0, 0, 0) for the entire corpus I am evaluating the results are different. I double checked that the accumulated lengths of the references are shorter than the length of the hypothesis, which should result in the brevity penalty being 1. Can you make sense of this?

Comment: What do you mean by "accumulated" lengths?  AIUI, each hyp/refs pair gets scored, then micro-averaged (?  http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.translate.html#nltk.translate.bleu_score.corpus_bleu), in which case you need to be sure that the brevity penalty _never_ applies?  Maybe ask directly for the brevity penalty: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.translate.html#nltk.translate.bleu_score.brevity_penalty

Comment: By "accumulated" lengths I meant the total length of all hyps/refs (I only have a single ref per datapoint). To my understanding when calculating BLEU on a corpus the brevity penalty is calculated for the entire corpus, not for individual sentences. At least that's how I am understanding the [BLEU paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P02-1040.pdf) and this also seems to be the behaviour [implemented by corpus_bleu() in nltk](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/translate/bleu_score.html). I have tried manually calling brevity_penalty as you suggested which returns 1.

Comment: Ah, you're right.
Maybe just the aggregation then?  Rouge looks to (maybe) just macro-average across a corpus (https://github.com/li-plus/rouge-metric/blob/c26bc5e00dc38dd7acad04e7d8d65d6479451e66/rouge_metric/py_rouge.py#L447, https://github.com/li-plus/rouge-metric/blob/c26bc5e00dc38dd7acad04e7d8d65d6479451e66/rouge_metric/py_rouge.py#L620), whereas BLEU does a micro-averaging?

Comment: Yeah, I just stumbled upon this as well. It seems that rouge-metric macro-averages scores. Correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't ROUGE use a micro-average as well, looking at the [formula for ROUGE-N in the ROUGE paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W04-1013.pdf)? Is the rouge-metric implementation wrong here?